# JavaFx not accepting Media Source file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

Hello I m trying to add a media in JavaFx I tried many solution already availble here on stack overflow and none of them seems to work for me , I tried this when I put the file in the src folder :

```
Media media = new Media("StartPageVideo.mp4");

// Create the player for playing media.
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
//set player property to autoplay
mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

// Create the view and add it to the Scene.
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
Ap_MediaContainer.getChildren().add(mediaView);
```

I tried also this when I put the video in a Video Package :

```
Media media = new Media("/Video/StartPageVideo.mp4");

    // Create the player for playing media.
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    //set player property to autoplay
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

    // Create the view and add it to the Scene.
    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
    Ap_MediaContainer.getChildren().add(mediaView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried using MediaPlayer yet, but the Javadoc states that its constructor takes a Media object as the parameter. The constructor of the Media object takes a URL *string*. So I suspect that you need to do something like the following:

```
Media media = new Media(getClass().getClassLoader()
             .getResource("/StartPageVideo.mp4").toString());
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code it work for me.

```
private static File file=new File("e:/videos/test.mp4");

private static final String source=file.toURI().toString();

Media media = new Media(source);

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

Try this hopefully work for you ..